# Can I take a screenshot of what's showing on the HDMI output in Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, screenshot, hdmi

I have a Raspberry Pi. Can I somehow, through the terminal, take a screenshot of what's running though the HDMI cable?

Answer (score 0):

The HDMI outputs the content of framebuffer. So you can get the payload of HDMI cable by taking a snapshot of framebuffer. Here's some tools of doing this [How to screen capture screenshots or movies on the Linux framebuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861472/how-to-screen-capture-screenshots-or-movies-on-the-linux-framebuffer).